# Git restore last detached HEAD

Tags: git

I have a big problem in my project: this is the scenario.
I have an xcode project under Git. Today I realized that the last commit broke some tests, so i checked out the previous commit.
I used SourceTree and this is the warning

> Doing so will make your working copy a 'detached HEAD', which means you won't be on a branch anymore. If you want to commit after this you'll probably want to either checkout a branch again, or create a new branch. Is this ok?

I worked for an entire day and at the end I committed everything.
So I needed to merge my work on develop branch so I checkout the develop branch and... my work instantly disappeared :(

I know it was wrong to detach my HEAD and Sourcetree warned me... but there is a way to restore my work?

Comment: A related thread for very same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10228760/465053) and the technicalities on how it happens [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/465053).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reconcile detached HEAD with master/origin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin)

Answer (score 350, accepted):

If you type `git reflog`, it will show you the history of what revisions `HEAD` pointed to. Your detached head should be in there. Once you find it, do `git checkout -b my-new-branch abc123` or `git branch my-new-branch abc123` (where `abc123` is the SHA-1 of the detached HEAD) to create a new branch that points to your detached head. Now you can merge that branch at your leisure.

Generally, if you check out a branch after working on a detached head, Git should tell you the commit from the detached head you had been on, so you can recover it if you need. I've never used SourceTree, so I don't know if it relays that message. But if it did display that message, then you should be able to use that to find the commit, and again use `git checkout -b` or `git branch` to create a branch from that commit.

Comment: I am new to git.. i am getting `fatal: A branch named 'mybranch' already exists.` How to add in existing branch?

Comment: To simply get back to the original HEAD on a particular branch, just `git checkout <mybranch>`.

Comment: fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'

Comment: As a PSA for all of those giving thanks to Brian:  If you're doing work that you don't want to lose, push it to a remote (e.g. github) every few hours.  When a meteor falls on your computer, you'll be glad you did.  If you're not yet ready to share it with collaborators, just put it in a branch that nobody knows about for now and then rebase it onto master later.

Comment: Also, if it's a single lost commit that just vanished and you found it there, you can bring that back with `git cherry-pick e5b2f7b`, where `e5b2f7b` is the SHA-1 of the commit there.

Comment: Thank you Dude, you are awesome, and saved also my life too! I love stackoverflow community.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I was on the verge of losing it when I found your answer. You've saved me from losing a week's work on commits to my local detached head that I thought I'd lost.

Comment: saved my life!!

Answer (score 14):

In Sourcetree, you can do this using the GUI.

First find the "lost" commit by looking for a message in the Command History (view:Show Command Output). It will probably be in the command "Switching Branch" after the commit that you lost. In that message, hopefully you'll see the commit comment with a 1234567 commit ID.

Take that Commit ID to next step.

Hit the "Branch" button in the top toolbar and you should get a dialog "New Branch" where you can specify a certain commit. Put that Commit ID in there, specify a new branch name, hit Create Branch  and you should get a new branch with your lost commit!

[image]

Comment: actually works. Make sure you see the correct comment with the commit id.

Comment: @blalond Hello, Having read your answer, I have a little question: When in SourceTree I double-click on a previous commit (in order to check it out) I get the same message that this would cause a detached head, so I wonder what it means when people say you can simply roll back to any previous revision with git? How do I roll back to a particular commit then? Thanks

Answer (score 12):

1. First, run `git reflog` to view history.
2. The oldest revision will be the last one in the list.
3. Switch to your desired commit using `git checkout -b temp e35d2b3` here e35dd23 is the hash value of your commit.
4. That's it. Now just do git add . etc....

Accept it as an answer if it solves your issue. Otherwise please share your comment.

Answer (score 5):

If you dont want to keep changes of detached HEAD and want to go to latest branch commit use below command directly.

```
git checkout -
```

**Note:I will delete all your changes in the detached HEAD.**

Comment: The OP did request to keep their work. This does not answer the original question. Just adding the option to keep that in a branch would make this answer useful.

Comment: troll answer!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

A colleague of mine just had this situation. In his case, there were commits in detached head --they work in R-Studio-- and the tool did warn them that they could create the branch with this and that SHA reference... but since the only option was "Close" --duh!! it was a info box-- they closed the dialogue and lost the info for ever...

Thanks to the `reflog` command we could see that the changes were not lost. But in our case, the `git branch` did not work as expected... or a incoming `git pull` did mess it up somehow. We had to fish the changes from the reflog to the newly created branch:

```
 git cherry-pick 0b823d42..3cce27fc
```

which placed all the commits we wanted in the branch. Then we could merge the branch into `develop` without issues.

Just in case this is informative for anyone, we did identify the commits on *detached head* in the `reflog` by looking at those in between the marked with "checkout" (which identify branch shifting):

```
e09f183b HEAD@{3}: pull: Fast-forward
b5bf3e1d HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from lost_changes to develop
b5bf3e1d HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from 3cce27fca50177a288df0252f02edd5da5ee64fd to lost_changes
3cce27fc HEAD@{6}: commit: add statistics
417a99a4 HEAD@{7}: commit: add test
0b823d42 HEAD@{8}: commit: new utility class
d9ea8a63 HEAD@{9}: checkout: moving from develop to d9ea8a635d4c2349fcb05b3339a6d7fad5ae2a09
b5bf3e1d HEAD@{10}: pull: Fast-forward
```

Those we wanted were `HEAD@{8}` to `HEAD@{6}` (both inclusive). So we got them by:

```
git cherry-pick 0b823d42..3cce27fc
```

Then the usual merge solving and final commit left us with branch lost_changes hosting the detached-head work that we thought lost. Merging that into develop was fast-forward this time.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this scenario, and find that git tell me SHA-1 of last commit:

```
vors@localhost:~/git-test$ git checkout master 
Warning: you are leaving 1 commit behind, not connected to
any of your branches:

  ec600e6 333

If you want to keep them by creating a new branch, this may be a good time
to do so with:

 git branch new_branch_name ec600e6eb2473dd4f3732539c5c1fa5829f631b7

Switched to branch 'master'
```

Did you see this message?

Comment: no. or maybe i don't pay attention. I'm looking for a backup on timemachine ;(

Comment: @IgnazioC You don't need to look at a backup. Did you take a look at my answer? `git reflog` should show you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

detached head is fine as long as you want to make No change.

If you want revert a commit, you can use git revert on specific branch

If you want to work off detached head and do commits; create a new branch (and later merge it);

Comment: Yeah! we do know the rules. But when the colleagues work off the detached head and then walk off those commits, they ask for answers, not rules.