# git HEAD detached from after reset --hard

Tags: git, git-detached-head

I needed to do away with changes that I made to the working directory and go back and start from the last commit, so I did `git reset --hard`

Now when I do git commit and git status I get this string in red saying "HEAD detached from: and some 7 char number.
I did few commits since then but not sure about this red message.

Did I muck it up and what am I suppose to do to "fix" it? or it is not broken? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reconcile detached HEAD with master/origin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a branch, then merge it/rebase it to the original branch (let's suppose master). It should solve the problem.

```
$ git checkout -b temp_branch
$ git rebase master
$ git checkout master
$ git merge temp_branch
```

Apparently you didn't just reset the workspace but moved the HEAD to another commit.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing is really broken, you're just on a detached HEAD. Simply give it a name, like any other branch, and continue working on it:

```
$ git checkout -b my_new_branch
```

Comment: how to go back to master?

Comment: @javadba you can use checkout: `git checkout master`.

Comment: figured that out. I had a couple of times over the years that I did not know what to do here: but now all is clear .

Answer (score 0):

You can find an answer here: [GIT restore last detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14757437/git-restore-last-detached-head)

Also, the Pluralsight video "How Git Works" explains how this happens and what to do about it.