# Git detached head issue

Tags: git

I've read many posts related to this issue today( one useful one here: [Fix a Git detached head?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228760/how-to-fix-a-git-detached-head)  & [Why did my Git repo enter a detached HEAD state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-git-detach-my-head)).

Today I've been scratching my head. I'm not able to understand how to fix this even after reading those articles.

Yesterday was all ok, I remember having given a checkout command. In the evening I found that Git was not showing any changes even though local changes were present. After researching today I could see now that git status is showing "HEAD detached from 99f040f".

Since then I removed .git folder in my D: (on my Windows 7) and restored .git of 27th July backup. Still not resolved. I tried 25th July version too. But no luck. So I've now restored yesterday's .git version.

I'm pasting the screenshot from gitk. Is there anything I can do to correct this issue?
[image]

Comment: `git checkout -b temp` to backup what you have right now, `git branch` to see what branches are in your repo, and then `git checkout <branchname>` to get to your desired branch.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: How can I reconcile detached HEAD with master/origin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/git-how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get back to the last checked-out branch, simply type

```
git checkout -
```

Seems a bit under-documented (search for `You may also specify` in the docs of [`git checkout`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html)), but works for me.
Could also be used as a handy shortcut for switching between two branches:

```
git checkout master
git checkout branchwithaverylongnamethatyoudontwanttotypeagain
git checkout - # brings back master
git checkout - # brings back branchwithaverylongnamethatyoudontwanttotypeagain
```

Comment: In the `<branch>` option description: You may also specify - which is synonymous with "@{-1}".

Comment: Note that for branches with very long names that you don't want to type again, git supports tab completion of branch names.

Comment: `branchwithaverylongnamethatyoudontwanttotypeagain1` vs. `branchwithaverylongnamethatyoudontwanttotypeagain2`?

Comment: branchwitha<tab> + 1 or 2! :)