# Can not push to a remote Git repository - Everything up-to-date

Tags: git, git-push, git-remote

I need to push my changes to a remote repo for the first time

```
// I added the other repo as a remote
$ git remote add devstage -f <Other-Repo>

// Merged the files from devstage to my local
$ git merge devstage/master -s recursive -X ours

// Executing Everything up-to-date
$ git push devstage HEAD
```

But the files were not really pushed to the Other-Repo.

Am I missing something?? None of the files in my local are staged. If I open a file stage it and push it to the remote it will be pushed.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the behaviour. The files are pushed to the other repo with your commands.

Answer (score 4):

A push shouldn't return everything is up-to-date, unless you are in a [detached `HEAD` mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309).

That would mean you git branch doesn't show any active branch (one with a '`*`' in front of it).
If that is the case, see "[How to fix a Git detached head?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10228760/6309)".

Also, rather than pushing HEAD, use a branch name.
For your first push:

```
git push -u devstage master
```

The `-u` establishes a tracking relationship with the [upstream branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244487/6309) `devstage/master`.
Then a simple `git push` will be enough for future pushes.
See why in "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)"