# Lost work doing a git checkout, how can I get it back

Tags: git

So... not sure how it happened, but I had been working in a branch a I made a couple changes, ran git add -A and then git commit (with a comment). Did that a few times, and then when I went to push up all the changes to the branch I was in, I got a message that said that the branch was already up to date. I couldnt figure out what the heck was going on, so I checked back out the branch and it overwrote everything.

Stranger still, now all the commits I made are gone when I run git log.

Any way I can get it all back? Or am I SOL and have to figure out why the heck it kicked me out of my branch for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in a detached HEAD (see "[Why did my Git repo enter a detached HEAD state?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309)").
You can confirm it with a `git status`.

Simply start by making a branch where you are:

```
git branch tmp
```

See [here one way to fix it (and keeping your commits)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20479669/6309), if you want to push `aBranch`:

```
git checkout aBranch
git merge tmp
```

`aBranch` should now include the commits you did, and you should be able to push it.

Comment: That was exactly right, with a caveat that somehow I was in a detached head of an entirely different branch than the one I had checked out last. I have on idea how these things happen -_- Thanks for the help!