# git: Pushing changes in particular commit

Tags: git, github

I've checked out particular commit:

```
git checkout xx
#made changes
...
git add .
git commit -m "abcd"
git push
```

But I don't see anything updated back in github site.
Please help me to push successfully to my forked repo.

Answer (score 2):

You have checkout a commit instead of a branch: you are in a detached HEAD mode, and a `git push` refuses to push a detached head.
See "[Why did my Git repo enter a detached HEAD state?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309)"

[image: detached head]

You need to make a new branch based on your current commit, or to reset one existing branch on that commit.
See "[git: switch branch without detaching head](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20479669/6309)".

Once your commit is referenced by a branch (as shown by the [`git branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) command), you will be able to push that branch on your remote repo.

---

Note: with Git 2.23 (August 2019), you can use [`git restore`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066072/6309) and [update your working tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57542268/6309) *without* detaching HEAD (since you do not switch branch).
To switch branch, you now have (again, Git 2.23) [`git switch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309).