# Why do I have a detached HEAD after checking out the most recent commit?

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-detached-head

Recently, while working in a git repository, I wanted to view the code at an old commit (`68cce45`), so I did

```
git checkout 68cce45
```

After viewing the changes, I wanted to return to the current version of the repository and keep working. Since `2bcfd11` was the most recent commit, I did

```
git checkout 2bcfd11
```

I then made some changes and did

```
git add *
```

and then

```
git status
```

which gave me the warning: `HEAD detached at 2bcfd11`.

I'm confused. I can understand why I would be in a "detached HEAD state" if the last commit I checked-out was several versions ago. But since the last commit I checked-out was the most current version of the repository, then why would I be in a detached HEAD state? Isn't HEAD now pointing to the "top" of the repository?

Comment: Don't forget the new `git restore` command with Git 2.23. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57542268/6309): no detached HEAD!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> why would I be in a detached HEAD state?

Because you've checked out a commit instead of a branch. Checkout any commit — and you're in a detached HEAD state.

> Isn't HEAD now pointing to the "top" of the repository?

`git` doesn't really knows if it's the top. You have to explain that to `git` by checking out a branch:

```
git checkout master
```

Now `git` knows it's the head of a known branch. The end of detached HEAD problem.

Comment: It's worth noting that a detached HEAD state isn't necessarily a problem. Checking out an entire branch isn't helpful if you're trying to experiment with a specific commit, which is when you'd typically checkout one. A developer may still wonder about the detached HEAD message, though.

Comment: @BrandonEssler You cannot check out an entire branch anyway. Branch is a pointer to a commit, so `git checkout master` doesn't checkout an entire branch `master`, it checks out the commit pointed to by `master`.

Comment: You are, of course, correct. But that's just semantics. I worded my comment poorly, but the point still stands. If you're checking out a specific commit, you want that one; not the commit a branch is pointing to.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on [phd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57541162/1256452) a bit: in Git, `HEAD`, spelled in all uppercase like this,<sup>1</sup> is a very special name.  `HEAD` can either be *attached* (to a branch name), or *detached*.  In both cases, Git will be able to tell you which *commit* you're using:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

will print some hash ID.  But only when `HEAD` is attached to a branch name can Git tell you which *branch name* you're using:

```
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD
git symbolic-ref HEAD
```

Both will give you the *name of the current branch* (prefixed with `refs/heads/`) if you're on a branch.  If you're in detached HEAD mode, the former will just print `HEAD` and the latter will produce an error:

```
$ git checkout --detach master
HEAD is now at 7c20df84bd Git 2.23-rc1
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD
HEAD
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD
fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref
```

Many forms of `git checkout` will *detach* `HEAD`.  A few forms will *attach* it.  Using `git checkout branch-name` attaches it, while—as shown above—you can add `--detach` to make sure it becomes or stays detached.

Using a raw hash ID such as `7c20df84bd` always results in a detached HEAD, even if there are one or more branch names that identify this particular commit.

Note that you can have as many branch names as you like that *all* identify *the same* commit:

```
$ for i in m1 m2 m3; do git branch $i master; done
$ git checkout m1
Switched to branch 'm1'
$ git rev-parse HEAD
7c20df84bd21ec0215358381844274fa10515017
$ git checkout m2
Switched to branch 'm2'
$ git rev-parse HEAD
7c20df84bd21ec0215358381844274fa10515017
```

If I explicitly check out `7c20df84bd21ec0215358381844274fa10515017`, which of the four names—`m1`, `m2`, `m3`, or `master`—would you like Git to use?  But it uses none of them: if you want it to use a name, you must supply a name yourself:

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
```

after which we can delete the extra names so that commit `7c20df84bd21ec0215358381844274fa10515017` is *only* on, and at the tip of, `master`, rather than being on and at the tip of four branches all at the same time.

```
$ for i in m1 m2 m3; do git branch -d $i; done
Deleted branch m1 (was 7c20df84bd).
Deleted branch m2 (was 7c20df84bd).
Deleted branch m3 (was 7c20df84bd).
```

Remember, `HEAD` has *two* functions.  It finds the current *branch* (name), or fails to do so if `HEAD` is detached; and it finds the current *commit*.<sup>2</sup>  The answer you get from Git depends on the question you ask: did you want to know the *branch name*, or did you want to know the *current commit hash ID?*

---

<sup>1</sup>You can, on some systems, sometimes spell it out in lowercase, `head`, and get the same effect.  However, this starts to fail mysteriously in added work-trees.  It's best to stick with the all-caps `HEAD`, or if that's too annoying to type, the single character `@` has the same special meaning.

<sup>2</sup>This too can fail, but only in a special state.  You are in this state in a new, totally-empty repository, in which your current branch *name* is `master`, but branch `master` itself does not yet exist.  This is because a branch name *must* contain the hash ID of some existing, valid commit object.  In a new, totally-empty repository, there are no commits at all.  So no branch names are allowed to exist.  Nonetheless, `HEAD` is attached to the name `master`.

When you're in this state—some parts of Git call this an *orphan branch*, as in `git checkout --orphan`, and others call it an *unborn branch*, as in what `git status` will say—the *next* commit you make causes the branch name to come into existence.  The name is already somewhere—specifically, stored in `HEAD`—but the commit creates the name as a valid *branch* name, after first creating a valid commit whose hash ID the name can hold.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The part about multiple branches being able to identify the same commit helps clarify things. In that case, with `git checkout <hash-number>` it wouldn't be clear which branch is being checked out.

Answer (score 0):

`HEAD` is whatever commit you currently have checked out. There may or may not be a branch (like `master` maybe) that points to `HEAD` or not. When you did `git checkout 2bcfd11`, you updated your `HEAD`, but remained detached - that is, you didn't indicate to git that you want to have some symbolic name associated with that. If you have a branch that points to `2bcfd11`, you can `git checkout` that branch and be fine. If you don't, `git branch` will let you create a branch at `2bcfd11` with whatever name you want.

Answer (score 0):

With Git 2.23 (released yesterday, August 2019), do a [`git restore`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066072/6309)

```
git restore -s <SHA1> -- .
```

You won't have a detached HEAD then (you remain on your current branch, `master` for instance, but with a different content).

Once you are done, you can, well, restore the proper working tree with:

```
git restore -s master -- .
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So just to make sure that I understand correctly, is this how I would use `git restore` in my case (referencing the SHA1 values I originally posted in my question)? To view the old commit, I would do `git restore -s 68cce45 -- .` instead of  `git checkout 68cce45`? And then to get back to the most recent commit I would do `git restore -s master -- .` instead of `git checkout 2bcfd11`?

Comment: @wxyz Yes. That way, you never *switch* branch, you are still on master branch after restoring master content.

Comment: Ah, ok. Also, what does the `-- .` do at the end of the command?

Comment: @wxyz it indicates the path of the content you want to restore: current path. Execute that at the root of the local repository, and you would restore the commit for the all working tree.

Comment: So could you leave the `-- .` off completely? Would that just restore the commit for the entire working tree?

Comment: @wxyz You have to put a path (unless you restore with the patch option: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore#Documentation/git-restore.txt--p). To restore the entire working tree (from any subfolder) you can use `-- :/` (see examples: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore#_examples)