# How can I commit the current state of my repo as master?

Tags: git

I'm having a problem with the master branch on a repo. I pulled the master branch in on a server, but that had an unforeseen error in it. In a slightly panicked fashion, I checked out a specific commit which I know still worked.

Now, the application works as it should, but my repo is "Not currently on any branch.". In the meanwhile, there have been changes made on the server itself (very bad practice, I'm aware) that I would like to keep.
So my question is - is there any way I can use the current state of my repo and turn that into "master"? I have looked into similar questions and those were solved by doing a merge with the "ours" strategy - but that won't work since I'm not on any branch, I think.

Comment: `git reset` can't cause `Not currently on any branch`.  Please give the *exact* steps you used.

Comment: @AdamSpiers I'm not actually 100% sure, unfortunately, I was kind of panicking. It might have been `git checkout [hash]` too, where that hash was the last "working" point of master branch.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fix a Git detached head?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228760/fix-a-git-detached-head)

Comment: Do you have a  `~/.bash_history` (or similar) to find the exact commands?

Comment: @Trengot - good call. Just checked, apparently I did check out a specific commit.

Comment: do you have some other commits that you want to keep after the commit where everything works? If not, just revert to the working commit. If you do have other work, then you have a few options. Depending on the fact if you work alone or not, you could rewrite the history of the branch, or just checkout a new branch from the working commit and then cherry pick the other commits you want and then merge it back to master (not very clean). You could also use git reflog to go back to the state before you did the unwanted changes/steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, and there's a few ways to go about it.  You didn't say much about
how your project is set up and whether or not your automatically publishing your
master branch.

*I highly recommend you try these techniques on a throw-away repo first, just to
make sure you know what you're doing before trying it on your live site.*

#### Option 1: Forcefully roll back master

First, save off your current version of master as old-master:

```
git branch old-master master
```

Now old-master and master point to the same commit.  Next, we'll update master
to point at your current commit:

```
git branch -f master HEAD
```

At this point, you'll still have a detached HEAD, but the local master will
point at the commit you are on.

```
git checkout master
```

This will put you back on your local master branch.

There are lots of details here beyond this though.  First is the question of
whether you should push up this change or not.  If you automatically publish the
master branch, then you you might consider doing a --force push, but that's
extremely unfriendly for your other developers on the team.  If you don't
automatically publish the site, then there's really not any harm in leaving
things as they are, fixing the whatever went wrong, and then updating the site
once all the kinks have been worked out.  The idea here is: if things don't move
automatically, then you don't have to worry about the rug being pulled out from
underneath your feet.  **I don't recommend this option.**

#### Option 2: Revert the bad commits

This is more friendly since you don't have to rollback history.  It's best to do
this in a separate clone of your repository so you don't have to change your
working tree that is being served until after master has been fixed.

Let's say commit WORKS is where everything is working fine, and BROKEN is the
current tip of master.  It's not clear whether there is more than one broken
revision, but assuming it is, then you can simply revert the broken commit.
**From another working tree**, you would do:

```
# In another working tree, *not* the one for your website
git checkout master
git revert BROKEN
git push origin master
```

If there's more than one commit breaking things, you can revert them all.  Just
watch out if any of those commits are merge commits.  You can revert an entire
range of commits too:

```
git revert FIRST_BROKEN_COMMIT..LATEST_BROKEN_COMMIT
```

This will revert all good commits in between too.  But this might be exactly
what you want, considering the situation.

Finally, you can update your website.  In the website's working tree, you can
use:

```
git fetch origin master
git push . FETCH_HEAD:master
git checkout master
```

While the commit number will change, the contents should not, unless you chose
not to revert some commits between WORKS and BROKEN.

Note: git will still see the reverted commits as part of the history, so
re-merging a branch will not re-introduce those changes.  Unfortunately, it
means that you either need to rebase the stuff that works and merge it in again,
or simply redo the work and re-introduce it.  There's a fair amount of help out
there for this topic, including on StackOverflow.

#### Option 3: Merge master into master

This uses a merge strategy to roll back master to the previous state.  It's not
any better than Option 2 in my opinion, but it's an option.

Again, you'll have to do this in a separate working tree.  Start by creating a
new-master branch based on the commit WORKS, though you won't keep it in the
end:

```
# In another working tree, *not* the one for your website
git checkout -b new-master WORKS
```

At this point, new-master should be pointing to the commit that you really want
to be the tip of master (the one that works).  Then merge in the tip of master
using the ours strategy:

```
git merge -s ours master
```

Make sure to put in a meaningful message for the merge, such as "Reverting the
site back to commit WORKS".

Now, we need to make the master branch the same as new master:

```
git push . new-master:master
```

If you get any error message about diverging, then it's likely you did something
wrong.  This new history will be a descendant of the broken master branch, so
there should be no diverging history.

You can finish this by pushing it up to your remote repo and dropping the
new-master branch:

```
git checkout master
git push origin master
git branch -d new-master
```

Finally, you can bring your website up-to-date as you would in Option 2:

```
git fetch origin master
git push . FETCH_HEAD:master
git checkout master
```

The commit number will change, but the contents should not as we made the tip of
master identical to the commit you are on.

#### Summary

Which one is better largely depends on you.  To me, I like Option 2 if there's
only a handful of commits involved, and Option 3 is there's more involved.  I'd
also chose Option 3 if you don't feel confident with Git--there's less to go
wrong.

Comment: Thank you.. This will definitely help me fix my mess :)