# Local Gitlab installation doesn't show all commits

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have configured Gitlab on a local server. When I push code to the origin , It shows only  half of commit history and skips rest of commits .

Here is my commit history on my computer: 
[image]

So my last commit is done today but my Gitlab setup shows latest commit of may 2015. Screen shot of the same:

[image]
What can be  probable reasons for it and how I can fix it?

Comment: Did you push in a branch different from master? In your first screenshot, what would a `git log --pretty=oneline --decorate` give you?

Comment: @VonC : Adding screenshot with this commands.Yeah , it seems I have done something wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HEAD without a branch means you are in a **[detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309)**.

A git push would only push a branch (a commit associated with a branch name), not your detached HEAD.

You can [fix that by creating a temporary branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20479669/6309) and merging it to master: it will fast-forward master to it.

```
# git add/commit first
git branch tmp
git checkout master
git merge tmp
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Issue is fixed now :)

Comment: @AbhijeetPanwar I have added the fix in the answer.