# Rstudio greyed out Git commands and (No branch)

Tags: r, git, rstudio

I am currently struggling with getting Rstudio to work with my git repositories. When I set up a new project and assign the git repository, the branch is set on Master and the commit, pull, and push buttons are all active. Everything works just fine. Then, at some point the branch is switched to (No Branch) and the commit, pull, and push buttons are greyed out (shown below). This happens to every single git project I make. Works at first then is greyed out.

[image]

I am still able to use git commands from Shell, but the GUI interface is not working.

I have spent some time looking through customer support forums and Googling the problem. One site that I found (https://www.r-bloggers.com/things-i-forget-pushpull-greyed-out-in-rstudio/) indicated that there is an issue with the configuration list. However, when I do `git config --list`, I find that I do `have branch.master.remote=origin` and `branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master` at the bottom of the configuration.

I also attempted a `git push -u origin master`, but that did not work either.

I use RStudio and github daily, and I would be so pleased if the GUI interface was working properly again.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me problem solve this issue.

EDIT: I am using OSX 10.9 Mavericks and Rstudio Version 0.99.903.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using OSX 10.9 Mavericks. I edited the original post to include this information.

Comment: Try looking at the remotes for a particular project. In the shell: `git remote -v`. There should be 2 lines there starting with "origin" and followed by the remote address. Is that what you see? Are there any remotes listed there at all? Also, is your remote repository "available" to you (if it's on a local network, are you connected to that network, and is the server active)?

Comment: @rosscova Thank you for your inquiry. Yes, when I use `git remote -v` is see two 'origin' lines with the url that goes to my git project: `origin https://github.com/username/rep.git (fetch)` The remote repository is available given that it is hosted on github and I have internet connectivity.

Comment: There should a be a log file at `~/.rstudio-desktop/log/rsession-<username>.log` (replacing your own username for `<username>`); do you see any exceptions within there that seem related to git?

Comment: @KevinUshey This was another good idea. I checked both that log file as well as the `rdesktop.log` file and searched both for 'git'. Both did not contain any information related to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Then, at some point the branch is switched to (No Branch) and the commit, pull, and push buttons are greyed out (shown below).

That is typical of a detached HEAD branch: see "[Why did my Git repo enter a detached HEAD state?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309)".

Revert to the command-line and check your `git status`.

You can [easily recover from this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10228760/6309) by a checkout of a branch.
Or by forcing a branch to your current detached commit

```
git branch -f branch-name HEAD
git checkout branch-name
```

Then switch back to RStudio: all options should be available again.

---

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39976526/rstudio-greyed-out-git-commands-and-no-branch/40030060#comment67567890_40139531):

> Tt turns out to be an RSA key issue.
>   The wrong key was in the Rstudio Config, which explains how Shell would work but not the Rstudio interface.

Answer (score 19):

I had a similar problem with a repo I had already configured locally and pushed and pulled from/to it using CLI (although I didn't have the problem of being detached from a branch) and I solved it by doing the following:

1. Open your console and navigate to your repo
2. Make some commit
3. Make a push using `-u` (i.e. `--set-upstream`) flag, eg: `git push origin master -u`
4. Open Rstudio (or restart it if it was open while performing the previous step) and you'll see the push and pull icons are no longer greyed out.

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to provide an update in case anyone in the future had a similar problem. While the answer provided earlier resulted in another temporary fix, I ultimately had to wipe my hard drive; reinstall the operating system; reinstall git, R, RStudio, and reconnect to my Github account before it would consistently work.

My solution may have been a bit overkill, but I have not had an issue with it since.

Comment: (https://xkcd.com/1597/)^2

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue today and found this post. I am going to share how I solve it:

on terminal (Git) type the following:
`$ git config --global user.name`
(it should return your Github username)

if username isn't correct just type
`$ git config --global user.name "correct_username"`

then type
`$ git config --global user.email`
(it should return an email associated to your GitHub account)

I found a typo in my email and fixed it by typing
`$ git config --global user.email "correct_email"`

Then I added the origin (this you get it from GitHub)
`$ git remote add origin https://github.com/my_username/my_repository.git`

Then I setup the branch, most used ones are main and master, in my case it is main
`$ git branch -M main`

then I pushed from the terminal
`$ git push -u origin main`

after that my pull and push buttons are active.

I hope this can save some time for others.