# git tag -l --merged does not show any tags

Tags: git, tags

I am using `git tag -l --merged` to see the tags that are applicable to my current branch.  This worked every where.

Today in one of the repository (created by Jenkins git plugin),  the command returns nothing.

What would be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

#### Start with `git status`

The command `git tag --merged` means `git tag --merged HEAD`.  That is, `--merged` needs a specific *commit ID*, which defaults to `HEAD`.  (The `-l` or `--list` is implied by the `--merged` option; you can use it, or not, as you like.)

It then finds (and lists) tags that meet the condition "is an ancestor" of the specified commit.  Or, equivalently, we can say that this lists tags where `HEAD` is a descendant of the tagged commit.

**Assuming the tags have not changed in any way,** if `HEAD` used to be listed as the descendant of one or more tags, and `HEAD` is no longer listed as the descendant of those tags, there is only one possible conclusion: that `HEAD` itself has changed somehow.  It's not normal for tags to change: that's kind of the point of a tag, to be an unchanging name for a specific commit.  So it's usually pretty safe to assume that the tags have not changed.

On the other hand, it's quite normal for `HEAD` to change.  `HEAD` *always* refers to the current commit, and it's quite normal to move about through history (to inspect or test previous commits) and to create new history (i.e., make new commits).  So the question now becomes: what is the current value of `HEAD`?

This value can be modified in two different ways.

- You can have a so-called "detached HEAD".  Here, `HEAD` contains a commit hash.  The value of `HEAD` is then simply whatever is in `HEAD`.  Use `git checkout` with some other commit hash to check out some other commit, i.e., to move this detached HEAD around (but see [Fix a Git detached head?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10228760/1256452) as well).  This is the normal way to work through history.

  There are other ways to move a detached HEAD around, e.g., using `git bisect` to pinpoint a commit that introduced a bug.  If you're in the middle of a bisect operation, you will also be in detached HEAD state.  (In this case, finish or terminate the bisect operation.)  Or, if you are in the middle of a `git rebase` that has paused due to your instructions (e.g., using `edit` in an interactive rebase) or a merge conflict, resume or terminate the rebase.
- Or, when `HEAD` is not in this "detached HEAD" state, it contains a branch name.  The value of `HEAD` is then the value of the corresponding branch name—but the branch name itself can be modified.

To check whether `HEAD` refers to a branch name or is detached, you can use `git status`:

```
$ git status
On branch master
...
```

or:

```
$ git status
HEAD detached at 8f60064
```

or similar.  "On branch ..." means "not detached".  If you are in the middle of a bisect or rebase, a modern Git's `git status` will tell you that as well.  Finishing that will take you back to whatever mode you were in before, probably "on branch *branch*".

If you are in detached HEAD mode—other than as part of an operation you need to finish—and wish to exit it, you can just check out any branch name with `git checkout`:

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
...
```

(but note that any commits you made while in this detached HEAD state are now left without a name—for much more, see [Fix a Git detached head?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10228760/1256452)).

If you *are* on a branch, this means that the tip commit of whatever branch you are on now is not a descendant of any of the tags.

If it *should be* (but now is not), you must have moved the branch name "backwards", using either `git branch` or `git reset`.  You will need to fix it, which can be more complex than fixing a detached HEAD.  It *may* be as simply as `git reset`-ing again to put the branch name back on the appropriate commit, but it may not.

If you are simply on the wrong branch, you just need to `git checkout` the correct branch again, so that you are back on the branch you intend.

Hence, the first thing to do at this point is to check `git status`.  Is your HEAD detached?  If so, solve *that*.  If not, are you on the correct branch?  If not, solve *that*.  Otherwise, figure out what you did to change the branch name's value, and solve that.

Comment: I am away from work today. Will check repo state and HEAD again by tomorrow

Comment: Great insight. Was having the same problem with --no-merge. Thanks.