# JGit checkout previous commit

Tags: java, git, jgit

How to tell JGit to checkout its parent? For example, if I have a situation like the one below on the master branch:

```
c815b27 newestCommit (HEAD -> master, origin/master, master)
e46dcaf previousCommit
b2d6867 previousPreviousCommit
```

I would like to call a command from JGit that would look something like:

```java
git.checkout().setName("c815b27~").call();
```

and would result in the state where HEAD would be moved to commit `e46dcaf`:

```
c815b27 newestCommit (origin/master, master)
e46dcaf previousCommit (HEAD)
b2d6867 previousPreviousCommit
```

However, when I call the above checkout statement nothing happens. I have also come across the following statement, which also does not move HEAD:

```java
git.checkout().setStartPoint("c815b27~").call();
```

Any ideas how to achieve moving to the previous commit based on tilde (~) or caret (^) symbols, and whether is even possible with the JGit API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to resolve the *expression* that points to the previous commit. Then you can checkout the resulting commit id.

For example:

```java
ObjectId previousCommitId = git.getRepository().resolve( "HEAD^" );
git.checkout().setName( previousCommitId ).call();
```

Note that checking out a commit [detaches HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228760/fix-a-git-detached-head).