# repo tool unable to pull based on tags

Tags: git, repo

Im using repo tool to manage multiple repositories.

Here is my sample manifest file and I have given a tag name in my revision - 'firsttag'.

When I do a repo sync it says -

```
Fetching project repo1
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/firsttag
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

xml file

```
  <!-- <default revision="refs/heads/master" -->
  <default revision='firsttag'
           remote="github"
           sync-j="4" />

  <project name="repo1" remote="github" path="repo1"/>
  <project name="repo2" remote="github" path="repo2"/>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`revision="firsttag"` or `revision="refs/heads/firsttag"` means a branch. For a tag, it should be `revision="refs/tags/firsttag"`.

If you are using Gerrit, you'll see a ref like `refs/changes/33/44433/1`. If you'd like to use this ref, it should be `revision="refs/changes/33/44433/1"`.

For a specific project, you could use both `revision` and `upstream` if you know the commit. It's very useful when you'd like an old commit of a branch. Note that `revision` in a project overrides the one in `default`.

```
<project name="repo1" remote="github" path="repo1"
         revision="3b9211fe8c87bf424c2bf128b1dec572375b318f"
         upstream="somebranch"/>
```

This is the output of `repo manifest -r`. The `upstream` can be a tag or any ref.

It's okay to use `revision` only if the value is a ref name.

```
<project name="repo1" remote="github" path="repo1"
         revision="refs/tags/secondtag"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, The tag works but when it clones the repo, it does not list any branches. It says "Not currently on any branch"

Comment: @user1050619 it works as design. `git branch -a` should list all the tracking branches. It's a bit like `git checkout <tagname>`, which will be in detached HEAD status.

Comment: Thanks. How do I change from the detached HEAD status pointing to HEAD of the tag?

Comment: It has already pointed to HEAD of the tag. The tag itself points to a commit and HEAD now points to the same commit.

Comment: ok, thats correct. How do I remove the "HEAD detached" or how do I attach to the branch?

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228760/fix-a-git-detached-head and https://source.android.com/source/using-repo . `repo start` may help but it may cause some problems. I can't tell in details. Have a try and you'll find it. And https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/docs/manifest-format.txt is useful.