# xcode source control doesn't show current branch

Tags: xcode, version-control

I'm using the standard xcode source control (version 9.3)

I just reopened my project and when I go to the Source Control Navigator:

1. It shows a long hex string at the top instead of the current branch name
2. None of the branches have '(current)' next to them

[image]

I have tried cleaning the project and also closing and re-opening.

Source Control->Commit brings up the standard commit interface with the option to leave a comment.

When I click on the very top row (with blue icon) I can see the new commits but they don't show in any of the branches.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at the following question: [Xcode Git Head Detached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49386739/xcode-git-head-detached/49392039#49392039)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

1. I clicked on the row with the long hex name. This brought up the version history for the current version.
2. I right-clicked the most recent change in the change history.
3. I clicked 'Branch from...' and created a new branch from that point.

Comment: If you want you can do a step 4: Merge this new branch into the branch that you believe should be the current one.

Answer (score 1):

For those wondering how something like this could have happened, it is caused when you checkout a commit rather than checkout a branch. Even if you checkout a commit inside the branch that is "current" (even the most recent commit), this will cause the branch to no longer have the "current" written next to it. So when you are sure that this previous commit that you have now checked out is the commit you want to work with, then you must do what Derek posted to do which is to "Branch from..." to make a temporary branch and then merge this temporary branch **into** the branch that this previous commit originally came from. And then you can delete the temporary branch. It is somewhat of a pain, but a good reason why Xcode does this is so that you are well aware that you are on a previous commit and that you should really make sure this previous commit is what you want your current branch to be at.