# git stuck in detached head - cannot revert to previous file in branch

Tags: git

I committed a change to my script that completely broke it. I tried restoring to a previous commit in git using this command:

```
git checkout 2af6889905af99b78f7401cb17b718ba86240c2a aws_utils.sh
```

But now I'm stuck in a detached head:

```
git branch -a
* (HEAD detached at 2af6889)
```

The branch that I am working in is called: update_aws_delete_user_function.

I am not working in the master branch currently.

How do I merge the functional file in the hash 2af6889 back into the main branch called origin/update_aws_delete_user_function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detached head means you are no longer on a branch, you have checked out a single commit in the history (in this case the commit previous to HEAD, i.e. HEAD^).

### If you want to *delete* your changes associated with the detached HEAD

You only need to checkout the branch you were on, e.g.

```
git checkout master
```

Next time you have changed a file and want to restore it to the state it is in the index, don't delete the file first, just do

```
git checkout -- path/to/foo
```

This will restore the file foo to the state it is in the index.

### If you want to *keep* your changes associated with the detached HEAD

1. Run `git log -n 1`; this will display the most recent commit on the detached HEAD. Copy-and-paste the commit hash.
2. Run `git checkout master`
3. Run `git branch tmp <commit-hash>`. This will save your changes in a new branch called `tmp`.
4. If you would like to incorporate the changes you made into `master`, run `git merge tmp` from the `master` branch. You should be on the `master` branch after running `git checkout master`.

From: [Fix a Git detached head?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228760/fix-a-git-detached-head)

Comment: Thanks! Sorry if I wasn't clear I am not working in the master branch. So can I just substitute the name of the branch that I am in instead of checking out the master branch? I've updated the OP for additional clarity.

Comment: Yeah just substitute your branch's name with master in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There are more complex ways to do this (e.g. revert), but what I would do is:

1. Copy your script to another location (your desktop in Windows for example).
2. Check out your  update_aws_delete_user_function branch
3. Put the file back in place
4. commit (-a)
5. push your branch