# Problem with head/master - how to change "head" to "master"?

Tags: git

I've made some reverts (with set back to Commit xxxxxx), now i have different entries than the other developers....

The other developers done a pull, but they have the entry "PF_WWW/master" / "master" Revert "- CSS Dateien komprimiert" on the top.

What do i need to do so all developers have the same entries? I think i need to changer my most top entry (- compression.php erneut hinzugefügt) to "PF_WWW/master" / "master"

[image: Repo Screenshot]

Thank you for your feedbacks.

Regards,
Hans

Comment: https://image.ibb.co/ekG0N9/Unbenannt.jpg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fix a Git detached head?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228760/fix-a-git-detached-head)

Comment: No, not a duplicate - at least not by myself.

Answer (score 2):

Your current `HEAD` is ahead of  `master` and  `PF_WWW/master`, i.e. have some commits on top of those on the other branches.

It looks like your `HEAD` is detached, i.e. you do not have a branch checked out. If this is the case, you can just use `git checkout master` to check out the `master` branch.

If you would be on another branch ahead of `master`, you could reset your `HEAD` with `git reset master`.

> What do i need to do so all developers have the same entries?

Every developer is responsible for their own local repository, you cannot change current branches/commits on other peoples machines (or, although possible, it's not advisable in a common workflow).

---

Your post looks like you should improve your understanding of how `git` handles its branches and commits. I heavily advise you to read some of the literature linked in the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/info), especially the [git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2), also available [in german](https://git-scm.com/book/de/v1).