# Detached HEAD in android studio

Tags: android, git, tfs, android-styles, git-detached-head

I am using TFS plugin in android studio. my last commit was buggy an I want to get back to last well commit. I go to version control and select `Checkout Revision` and that put me in Detach head state. I do not know about git command line and only work with TFS plugin. How can I get ride of this?

Comment: do u have any code to commit? if not do a hard reset `git reset --origin/yourBranchName`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fix a Git detached head?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228760/fix-a-git-detached-head)

Comment: Try the command `git update-ref refs/heads/<branch> HEAD`. Replace "<branch>" with the real branch name. In your case you needed `git reset <revision> --hard` instead of `git checkout <revision>`. I'm not familiar with Android Studio, but I'm sure you can find the corresponding menu items and checkboxes to do the hard reset.

Comment: @Anmol is there any change in GIT master or other branches in stash for these command? or its only affect locally in my android studio.