# git push says everything is up to date when it appears not to be

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm working on a new project and haven't been using any branches. At each development milestone I've been issuing the following commands from the root directory of my project:

```
git add *
git commit -m *some meaningful text*
git push origin master
```

I'm using a free account on bitbucket.org. git reports that everything is up to date, yet when I browse the repository it doesn't appear like any of my changes in the last 3 weeks are stored there. 'git log' shows all the recent commits I would expect to see.

I suspect I did something 3 weeks ago to stop it working but I have no idea what or how to restore the correct operation. I've not used any branches and am only working on the master.

Comment: Does `git remote -vv` list the url you are expecting?

Comment: Yes, git remote -vv is showing the correct bitbucket url.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging around I discovered the problem was a detached HEAD. I've found an answer to another question which fixed the problem, linked here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10229202/2244193