# Why is my git push only pushing up to commits pointing to master and why it cannot push every commit after commit pointing to master?

Tags: git

I am having trouble in pushing my commits to the online git repository

[image: .]

When I use git push -u origin master, it only pushes up to point "Components Part 2" while the recent commit is "test". I don't get why is it not pushing every commit? And how can I solve this problem? Please explain.

Comment: Is there any branch other than `master`? I don't see `HEAD` and `master` together which is the reason why the push isn't working

Comment: @Arvind, no there is no branches, just the master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HEAD is detached from master.
This means HEAD is not attached to any branch i.e. HEAD points directly to some commit.

That is why whatever commit pointing to master is getting pushed and not your recent commit.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228760/fix-a-git-detached-head) to know more and fix this.