# My head and master are separated(git). How can I rejoin them back together?

Tags: git

```
commit b438d02c93a4678276036cd8201e0e53774a2adb (HEAD)
Author: James <test@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 12 13:32:42 2021 +0100

    I fixed the input element on the user form

commit 684ec9c25e0320571173c29907029e9202950c43 (origin/master, master)
Author: James <test@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 12 11:57:43 2021 +0100

    I added user form

commit d65c75387d02b89a6d593522950480fbdcb7cc65
Author: James <test@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Jul 7 17:32:08 2021 +0100

    update README
```

- My head and origin are not aligned(embarrassing right?).
  I have checked-out to master `git checkout 684ec`.
  I commited `I fixed the input element on the user form` and pushed it to my remote(github) but got 'everything up to date'.
- When I have `git log` I saw that it was committed on Head again which is not same as master.
- As you can see I literally *lost my head*. How can I go back to master. I don't mind to give up on my last commit(`I fixed the input element on the user form`).

What should I do to go back to master and be well-organised?

PS
I haven't opened branch because its my own personal project, no collaborators

Comment: "I have checked-out to master `git checkout 684ec`" No. You've checked out *the commit* `master` happened to currently point at. Just get `master` to point at your new commit, now. With `git checkout master` then `git merge b438d02c9`, it will be a fast-forward, and you'll be set.

Comment: ... and HEAD is always where you are. So HEAD and a branch are not togetjer, it means you checked out something else, no embarrasment, actually.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix a Git detached head?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228760/how-do-i-fix-a-git-detached-head)

Answer (score 0):

A branch is just a pointer to a commit, but checking out that commit by hash isn't the same as checking out the branch.

You're detached, so just check out master now. Cherry-pick the missing commits if necessary.