# HEAD is detached in the repository [repo_name] and no branch selected - NetBeans

Tags: java, git, netbeans, git-branch, git-detached-head

I'm using NetBeans to develop a project in Java. Whenever my mate tries to push what he has done, it shows the error:

> HEAD is detached in the repository [repo_name]

When I go to the `Repository Browser` in his program it shows that no branch is selected, but I can't solve that problem, we've already tried many ways, including using the cmd from git, but we can't sync it with the NetBeans project.

Comment: What specifically have you tried? For example, have you reviewed all of the answers in [How do I fix a Git detached head?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10228760/12567365) and various similar questions?

Comment: Why do you believe that a detached HEAD is a problem? (Note: I'm not claiming it *isn't* a problem. But I'm not suggesting that it *is* a problem either. I am asking for more information about your setup. What command(s) are you running and what do you expect them to do? See also [mre] and [ask]. My guess–the *guess* part is crucial here—is that something has gone wrong much earlier, and fixing the detached HEAD won't help at this point.)