# Unable to find current origin/master revision in submodule path

Tags: git, git-submodules

In my project (which uses `git`), I need to use [a library](https://github.com/mb21/JSONedit), which is still in progress. I decided to create a submodule for that library, because I want to update from time to time its latest version (I don't plan to make my own change there).

I did:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/mb21/JSONedit.git
git commit -am 'added JSNedit submodule'
git push -u origin master
git pull origin master
```

Then, I did see the JSONedit folder in my local folder, and a link in my git folder online. But when I did `git submodule update --remote JSONedit/`, I got the following errors:

```
fatal: Needed a single revision
Unable to find current origin/master revision in submodule path 'JSONedit'
```

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Running this in the main repository should do the trick:

```
git pull --recurse-submodules
```

According to the other discussion, especially as [@Tobu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229753/tobu) [pointed out in his comment over there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8573310/537554#comment-15144961), if the error persists, it might be needed to first:

> remove both the submodule worktree (ext/blah) and the matching folder inside the **GIT_DIR** (`.git/modules/ext/blah`)

---

Alternatively, you could `git checkout` the branch from which you want to pull while inside the submodule, and then run a `git pull`.

Results should be the same.

Comment: So if I just do `git pull origin master` in the main repository, it will not pull the submodules, right?

Comment: Also I think it should be `git submodule foreach --recursive git pull`, otherwise it gives an error `fatal: Couldn't find remote ref master`.

Comment: Actually, does this work for you @SoftTimur `git pull --recurse-submodules`. This is a better approach.

Comment: it returns `Fetching submodule JSONedit Already up-to-date.`, it seems to work...

Answer (score 47):

In my case, the problem was that Git submodule assumed there would be a branch ***origin/master***. Instead, the submodule repository only had a branch ***main***.

I added `branch=main` to the submodule definition in `.gitmodules`. After running `git submodule sync`, `git submodule update --remote` now works fine.

Comment: This solution worked for me. The submodule clone in a jenkins job is limited w.r.t configuration.

Comment: this is probably the most common reason at present (2022+) due to the change n default branch naming from `origin/master` to `origin/main`

Comment: My problem was that `branch` was set to `remotes/origin/master`. Changing it to just `master` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 20):

I faced the same problem. It got solved. the folder in which the submodule would be stored was there. when I deleted the folder manually, it got resolved.

Comment: I also faced this problem in a jenkins pipeline and solved it by deleting the folder

Answer (score 11):

It seems that this problem was already solved in this thread:
[Git submodules - pulling into a new clone of the super project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605469/git-submodules-pulling-into-a-new-clone-of-the-super-project).
In short you should try:

```
# rm -rf JSONedit
# git submodule update
```

Answer (score 8):

```
fatal: Needed a single revision
Unable to find current origin/master revision in submodule path
```

- I face this kind of issue...
- I fix this by updating the git version

Comment: Surprisingly, updating from 2.24.3 to 2.36.0 really did fix my issue.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, error log is

> Unable to find current origin/HEADER revision in submodule path 'JSONedit'

This was because my multimodule not recognize submodule's checkout branch.
I fix this by setting submodules branch in `.gitmodules` file.

In multimodule directory

```
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.{submodule name}.branch {branch name}
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.JSONedit.branch main
```

I think you probably don't have master instead main.
check your branch in submodule directory by command 'git branch'.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had deleted and cloned again a project, but the commit stored by git for my submodule did not exist in the origin repository anymore. So I did :

```
$ rm -rf <submodule name>
$ git clone <submodule url>
$ cd <submodule name> 
$ git checkout <whatever commit/branch you wanted>
$ cd <main project>
$ git add <path/to/submodule>
$ git commit -m "fixed my submodule"
$ git push
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this for a Jenkins build with a submodule that indeed was using `origin/main` instead of `origin/master`. I found I was shooting myself in the foot by turning on the option to **"Update tracking submodules to tip of branch"**. Turning it off resolved the error:

[image: Jenkins Advanced sub-modules behavior]

In my case this option is not what I actually wanted, since I use specific commit ids in the submodules.