# git get latest submodule version

Tags: git, github, gitlab

In my own gitlab repo I have included a public, third party submodule from github. `git submodule status` shows me the submodule points to an older commit. `.gitmodules` tells me the path and url (`https://github.com...`). Now, I want to get the latest version.

The suggestions in
[Update Git submodule to latest commit on origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828324/update-git-submodule-to-latest-commit-on-origin)
results in

```sh
git checkout master
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

`git submodule update --init --recursive` seems to do nothing.

```sh
git submodule update --remote --merge
fatal: Needed a single revision
Unable to find current origin/master revision in submodule path '...'
```

Then trying (from [Unable to find current origin/master revision in submodule path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987847/unable-to-find-current-origin-master-revision-in-submodule-path))

```
git pull --recurse-submodules
```

It pulls from my gitlab (`Already up to date.`), but not the latest commit from github.

I'm not sure if, I messed anything up.

Comment: They probably renamed their `master` branch to `main`. You'll need to do the same in your settings.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with running in the submodule:

```
git reset --hard
git pull
```

And then outside of the submodule

```
git commit -m "update" submodule
git push
```